# How to express nested attribute in let helper on RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I can't figure out how to express nested attribute.
Article has many ArticleCategory.
And I'd simulate this kind of parameter.

`[:article][:article _categories]["0"][:category _id] = 40001`

And I express this parameter by using let.
Belows are my Rspec code.

```
  let(:article) {
    {
      article_categories_attributes:[
        category_id: ["40001", "40002"]
      ]
     }
```

But I think this expresses article[:article_categories_attributes][:category_id].
How to express ["0"]?
I'd appreciate if you could solve this.

[appendix] Strong_parameter

```
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:id, :current_version , :publish_version, :file, :status, :user_id , :update_user_id, :publish_at, :publish_until, article_categories_attributes: [:article_id, {:category_id => []}], article_tags_attributes: [:article_id, {:tag_id => []}], article_histories_attributes:[:id, :article_id, :version, :title, :content, :comment], articles_article_series_attributes:[:article_id, :series_id, :num])
  end
```

Comment: What to you try to achieve? Do you want to override the `category_id` value or read the existing value of `category_id`? What is `:article` in this context?  It feels to me like you need to add more code to your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I modified the script. Could you check it?

Answer (score 1):

If what you really are looking to do is just associate an Article and Category you don't need `accepts_nested_attributes`.

Lets say you have these models:

```
class Article
  has_many :article_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :article_categories
end

class Category
  has_many :article_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :article_categories
end

class ArticleCategory
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :category
end
```

You can create an article and associate it with categories 1,2 and 3 with:

```
Article.create(title: 'Hello World', category_ids: [1,2,3]).
```

In that  case the params hash would read:

```
let(:params) do   
  {
    article: {
      title: 'Hello World',
      category_ids: [1,2,3]
    }
  }
end
```

ActiveRecord creates `_ids` setters for all `has_many` and `has_and_belongs_to_many` associations. If the association is indirect Rails handles inserting the join model as well.

Don't bother trying to do it with `accepts_nested_attributes` - it won't work when creating records since the record does not yet have an ID.

You're also nesting the strong params insanely.

Don't write strong params in a single line. Follow the 72 character per line convention so that you can actually read the code.

```
params.require(:article)
      .permit(
        :id, :publish_version, :file, :status, :user_id, 
        :update_user_id, :publish_at, :publish_until,
        :categories_ids, :tags_ids,
        article_histories_attributes:
          [:id, :article_id, :version, :title, :content, :comment]
       )
```

Comment: PS. Use `let` with `do end` for multi-line declarations. https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#single-line-blocks

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I almost forgot. Due to strong parameter, it didn't work correctly. Could you tell me how to express nested model in this case? I appended the definition of strong parameter.

Comment: What do you mean? Two levels of nesting? That is an example of how you create nested records.

Comment: Sorry, it might be so. When I run the code you answered, debugger showed "article_categories_attributes"=>[<ActionController::Parameters {} permitted: true>, <ActionController::Parameters {} permitted: true>]
So, I assumed this might be caused by strong parameter definitions. In this case, what should I do?

Comment: I ediited it. If you are just looking to create a an article and assign  categories to it at the same time you don't need nested attributes. Just use `categories_ids`

Comment: The same with tags. Just use `_ids` and rails will create the join model for you.

Comment: Is that so? OK I'll apply it and get back to you when it turns out. Thanks!

Comment: I applied what you wrote, and then it works well. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let(:article) {
{
  article_categories_attributes:
  {
    "0"=>{"category_id"=>"40001"},
    "1"=>{"category_id"=>"40002"}
  }      
 }
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. I missed my strong parameter. I rewrote the issue. Could you tell me how?